# Can Auth0 allow Client Credentials Flow allow the client to send additional information that can be added as claims to the token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect, auth0

I need Auth0 (using the Client Credentials Flow) to allow the client to send additional information that can be added as claims to the token. So for example, when the client calls `/oauth/token`, they can pass an additional bit of information that will be included as a claim inside the token return to the client.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These claims are called "Scopes" and you can use the default "oidc" scope or define scopes in the identity provider. There are also attributes that you can define and use for authorization, although scopes are the preferred approach.The attributes are tied to the oauth application itself while scopes are selected during the oauth/token call.